# Help identify this loop frame bike

Tags: frames, identify-this-bike, vintage, australia

I'm trying to find out more information about this old loop frame bike I'm planning to refurbish. I haven't found any other marks that may be identifying, if there's anything else I can take a photo of that might help, please let me know.
Other information is that it was bought locally in Western Australia, so it's likely that it was bought either here or somewhere in Australia.

Edit 1:
I found an identifying name on the rear hub and coaster brake lever, photos added below, I can't quite make out what it says.
Also, I had a response from the WA Historic Cycle Club saying that the chain ring looks to be a Williams and it should have a date code that can be decoded here: http://www.classiclightweights.co.uk/williamsdating.html

Edit 2:
Started pulling it apart and found a stamp on the chain ring that has a "46" in the middle of text circling it "BAT.NO.10898-47" The letter at the beginning is worn, but I'm assuming it is a B. The drive side crank has the "B.T.M" stamped on it. I haven't been able to find anything useful from those. There may be another stamp, but the paint is quite thick in some parts so it's hard to tell. Images of these are below.

Edit 3:
So I've started removing the top two blue layers of paint to reveal the original paint(or what's left of it). Unfortunately, most of the likely spots for logos or names have been sanded previously.

There is a logo of some sort on the seat tube along with another dutch flag at the bottom. You can also see that there is dark green paint in the middle of the seat tube and it looks like there is a dark pink/magenta colour down the bottom. This matches with the down tube that appears to be magenta faded to dark green(possibly grey or a lighter colour in between?)

The drive side down tube has some brighter bits of paint where there was previously paint or stickers.
On the non-drive side of the down tube I think I can see an "e".

I'll continue removing paint, it's quite time consuming, I'm using a hobby knife to lift off the old paint. This still isn't much to go off, but it's a lot more than before. I've also included pictures of the handlebars and stem, I tried cleaning them up a bit to see if there are any stamps, but I can't see anything. Please let me know if there is anywhere specific on the bike that I should focus on.

Edit 4:
I've made the biggest discovery by far today, I've added the picture in above all the others. On the steerer tube there is a label with what I assume is the manufacturer's name because it's a guarantee sticker. Unfortunately I can't find anything about them except that they maybe part of "The Nissan Cycle Co." You can see the label below, it says "Super Yama". Hopefully someone knows something. You can also clearly see one of the original colours, it was hidden under a crown cover.

Edit 5:
Just found another thing on the WA Historic Cycle Club site, they have a page with WA bike manufacturers logos, and I'm almost certain this is the one on the seat tube, I've added the logo down with the pictures of the seat tube.

[image: Super Yama Guarantee Sticker]

[image: Whole bike]

[image: Identifying mark on seat tube]

[image: Identifying mark on seat clamp]

[image: Whole bike, front side]

Edit 1 Images:
[image: Rear coaster brake lever]
[image: Rear Hub]

Edit 2 Images:
[image: Crank]
[image: Chainring]

Edit 3 Images:

Stem
[image: Stem]

Handlebars
[image: Handlebars]

Logo that appears to match - Bluebird Boans Ltd. Perth
[image: Bluebird Boans Ltd. Perth]

Seat tube front logo with flash
[image: Seat tube front logo flash]

Seat tube front logo no flash
[image: Seat tube front logo no flash]

Seat tube non drive side
[image: Seat tube non drive side]

Seat tube drive side
[image: Seat tube drive side]

Down tube drive side no flash
[image: Down tube drive side no flash]

Down tube drive side flash
[image: Down tube drive side flash]

Down tube non drive side
[image: Down tube non drive side]

Comment: Cottered cranks says its 1970's at latest.   The front wheel hub looks like a racing bike I used to own, so probably not original front wheel.   Shame there's no brakes - they're pretty handy for dating.  No brake lever or mark implies it might never have had handbrakes.  Is it a coaster brake?

Comment: Those seat stays - are they bolted in at both ends?  Because that's exceptionally weird.

Comment: Do you think the second picture might show a flag?  AFAIK that flag is Luxembourg and the Netherlands, depending on shade.  It might just be some coloured panels rather than a flag.

Comment: The bike is from some time before 1980.   How long before is hard to guess, but I would, as a thumb suck, say the 50s or 60s.  Better than average quality (but nothing exotic).  If the wheels are original you might be able to get some info off the hubs that will help identify it.

Comment: It does have a coaster brake, doesn't look as though there have been other brakes on it.

Comment: The seat stays are bolted at both ends, but at the wheel end the bolts are cut welded on the inside.

Comment: This suggests a Czech origin of the *Favorit* brand: http://velobase.com/VeloBase.com/ViewBrand.aspx?BrandID=04485cbb-d57c-4a9f-82d7-a59c20faaec8&From=T

Comment: And apparently they're still around: https://www.favorit.cz/en/favorit/technology

Comment: Apparently, the original Favorit company closed and the name was bought and now used by the current Favorit that you have linked to. Thank you for bringing it to my attention though. There is still a connection so I have emailed them to see if they can help anyway.

Comment: Curiously, the Czech flag has had those three colours in the past, but not in that order.

Comment: Can't make out whether that crank arm says "DTM" or "BTM".  I'm thinking that "DTM" was a British brand, but don't quote me on it.

Comment: The flag on the seat tube seems to be Dutch. And the frame shape is very popular in continental Europe. I also know that some of the Dutch bikes were equipped with Favorit coaster brake. Can you take some pictures of the head tube and the stem? Some Dutch brands stamp their name there.

Comment: Looking at the three letters on the cranks again I would still say it's BTM, it could be a "D" but it seems more like a "B".

Comment: I've added pictures of the headtube and stem, there doesn't seem to be anything on them, but please let me know if there is a specific area that I should clean up.

Comment: I emailed Favorit, I was only half expecting a response, they had a look but couldn't provide any more information.

Comment: With regards to the Dutch flag, I'm cautious not to get too drawn down that path. I'm in Australia, I'm not sure how likely it is that a Dutch bike came here 50 years ago, from the little I've gathered, there seems like there were plenty of these type of bikes being sold here. Could it be possible that it was trendy to have a Dutch style bike and the flags were added to make it seem European?

Comment: Well, it looks like you've made a good amount of progress. Regarding a Dutch bike exported to Australia, the Netherlands are currently the leaders in bike exports. Dunno about 50 years ago. But, it appears you've found a much more likely candidate -- an Australian brand. Now that you have a brand, a likely next course of action is to find old catalogs of theirs (which may be difficult).

Comment: Boans was a department store in Perth, WA, it looks as though all of their bikes were called Bluebirds, there were kids, ladies, mens, racers, but they were all Bluebirds.